# XML-RPC getting values from response

Tags: xml, rpc

I have problem with my XML-RPC response which looks like this

`<member><name>name</name><value><string>test_test_1</string></value></member>`

and I want to get `test_test_1` value and I dont have idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the methods for it? If you don't try get the methods out first by using:

```
print server.system.listMethods()
```

After you found out your method, get the signature so it's easier for you to do a search on it.